# IndexError: Tuple Out of Range

Tags: python, tuples

So I am getting an error that states Tuple is out of range and was hoping that I could get some insight into what is going wrong

```
num_data=data.shape[3] # number of curves in the files
cscale=['k','r','b','y']

for i in range(num_data):
    plt.plot(data[:,i*2],data[:,i*2+1],label=header[0,i*2+1],color=cscale[i],linewidth=2) 

plt.xlabel(header[0,0]+' (ps)',size=20)
plt.ylabel('Counts (a.u.)',size=20)
plt.axis([-20, 120, -.1, 1])
plt.title("Prova",fontsize=20)
plt.xticks(fontsize=10)
plt.yticks(fontsize=10)
plt.legend(loc=1)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig(file_id_out,dpi=300)
```

Any advice would be appreciated! Many thanks

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including the full error message. You can [edit]. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: if the error says that tuple is out of range it most probably means that you tried to access an index that doesn't exist, for example if you had this tuple: `tpl = ('item 1', 'item 2')` and you tried to do this: `tpl[2]`, it will throw that error, why? because the tuple only has two items and the index is trying to access item that is third in the tuple, however it is pretty clear that there is no third item in that tuple (tuple indexing starts from 0 (as first item) btw)